# How to show the Person column image in bigger size?

Tags: person

The default image size of the Person column type is quite small. How to show that in bigger size?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the src of the Image tags created by Sharepoint. You will see that the URL of the image has a parameter for size.

Just run this script on page load; this will change the URL of all the person images -

```
  window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    $("img.ms-peopleux-userImg").each(function () { var src = $(this).attr('src'); src = src.replace('SThumb', 'LThumb').replace('size=S', 'size=M'); $(this).attr('src', src); });

});
```